# Compile unix program coded from Linux in Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix

I am trying to compile the unix code made in Linux system in OS X.
Several .so files are not existing in Mac OS.
Should I change the code lines to refer .a instead of .so?

libblas.so
libdlib.so
libhdf5.so
libhdf5_cpp.so

The below error shows up when compile the codes.

```
No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libblas.so',
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is for [tag:c++]? If I recall correctly, depending on the distribution, `unix` and `linux` don't use the same compilers and the same libs. `linux` usually uses the `GNU` [tag:gcc] when `unix`distros like [tag:freebsd] and [tag:macos] use the `POSIX` [tag:clang]. Though, `clang` [should be compatible with `GCC`](https://clang.llvm.org).

Take this with a grain of salt as it's all coming out from the back of my head. This is more to try to guide you in your search.

Comment: `.so` files (shared libraries) have a `.dylib` extension in macOS, not `.a`, so you can replace `.so` with `.dylib`, but there may be an easier way to do it. Most software packages available in source code include a `README` file with information on how to compile the software, which you should read. Usually, a `configure` script is also included. `configure` that takes care of details like  extensions. If `configure` is present, run it like this `./configure --help | less` to get usage help.